# Run standalone java app with sockets on google app engine

Tags: java, sockets, google-app-engine

I want to ask if it is possible to use the free tier of google app engine or any other free PAAS to run standalone java application that opens outgoing sockets to an MQTT server.

I 've deployed to Heroku but, in a couple of months, it will no longer be free.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would ask to consider whether you are able to pay $5/month because you can get a real server (VPS) for this price. I remember that when I was around 15-16 I learned that I couldn't have anything online that cost money, and it took a while to unlearn that.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 flavors of Google App Engine environment - Standard and Flex.

According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments), Standard doesn't support Web Sockets whereas Flex does.

Since you talked about 'free', you should note that 'Standard' can essentially be free because an instance can go down when there's no traffic. This means that if you stay within the daily free quota, you essentially run your App for free.

Flex on the other hand requires at least 1 instance to be always up (even when you have no traffic) which means you're more than likely to incur a cost when you use Flex.